# Servlet and xml file

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, ibm-cloud

how to write web.xml for 2 servlet-class and url-pattern??

I have this:

```
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>       

<servlet-class>example.nosql.X</servlet-class>    
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>X</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>

       <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
         <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>       
<servlet-class>example.nosql.Y</servlet-class>    
</servlet>



        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>Y</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>
```

how to merge these 2, it is not working
only X is working if commenting Y

Comment: Indent your code. It's unreadable. And don't start it in the middle of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple `url-pattern`

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>X</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>Y</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr154/servlet-2_5-changelog.html#pgfId-1042938